# How do I deal with 'no module named library_name' error using Python with Matlab's system function?

Tags: python, matlab

When I try to run a Python script in Matlab using the system command, it works find until I import something that doesn't come with base Python.

For example, if I have a script test_1.py:

```
import math as m
print 'good to go'
print m.exp(7)
```

and I run the Matlab command:

```
>>> system('python test_1.py')
```

I get back

```
good to go
1096.63315843

ans = 

    0
```

which is what I want. But if I modify test_1.py to be

```
import math as m
import pandas as pd
print 'good to go'
print m.exp(7)
```

and run

```
>>> system('python test_1.py')
```

I get:

```
>> system('python test_1.py')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas

ans =

     1
```

Both scripts run fine when I run them in my Bash terminal and the problem doesn't seem to be specific to the Pandas library.

I checked Matlab's documentation and some other StackOverflow questions but I can't find anything closely related to my issue.

Comment: How did you install pandas? Is it installed within a virtualenv?

Comment: @Suever It is not a virtualenv. I used Anaconda. That might be my problem now that I think about it

Comment: Can you compare `which python` called from bash and from MATLAB?

Comment: @hbaderts I just checked. They're different. Matlab calls /usr/bin/python and Bash calls /Users/JackStClaire/anaconda/bin/python Do you know if I can change the call in Matlab?

Comment: @JackSt.Claire: can you try: `system('source activate;python test_1.py')`

Comment: @TheBlackCat it gave me two errors. The first was /bin/bash: activate: No such file or directory and the second was the 'ImportError: No module named pandas'

Comment: In bash can you try `which activate`, then replace `activate` in my previous comment with the full path?  So say `which activate` gives `/Users/JackStClaire/anaconda/bin/activate`, use `system('source /Users/JackStClaire/anaconda/bin/activate;python test_1.py')`.

Comment: @TheBlackCat this and hbaderts answer got me to the answer! Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing Anaconda with default settings, it will automatically add the Anaconda binaries to your `$PATH` variable. If you choose not to, you can add it manually by adding the following line to your `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile` on Mac) file:

```
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Now, in your case, this has happened (in either way), so Anaconda does work in your bash shell. On Mac OS X, however, there are two different `$PATH` variables: the bash path, and the `launchctl` path. The bash path is used if you open a terminal, or run a program from the terminal. The `launchctl` path is used when you run a program "the normal way", which is with the `launchctl` command. Now, your bash path is correct, but your `launchctl` path isn't - that is why it works in a terminal, but not from MATLAB.

You can either set the `launchctl` path to be the same as the bash path, by adding the following line to your `.bash_profile`:

```
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
```

This changes the path settings for *all* programs, which might be undesirable. So, it might be easiest and safest to add the Anaconda binaries to the path from within MATLAB with the [`path`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/path.html) function, at the start of your script:

```
path('Users/JackStClaire/anaconda/bin/', path)
```

By adding it to the beginning of your `$PATH` variable, which makes sure that it uses the Anaconda `python` and not the system `python`.

Answer (score -1):

In the Matlab script you can simply set the environment that Python use to communicate with its libraries to be sure that it is the right one

```
PATH_PYTHON = '/Users/matteofabris/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/';
setenv('PYTHONPATH', PATH_PYTHON);
```